# Unhandled Exception: type 'int' is not a subtype of type 'String' in type cast in the code error?

Tags: php, flutter, dart

I am trying to store the latitude and longitude in the database using API using following function:

```
      Future update_location(latitude,longitude) async {

    var response = await http.post(Uri.parse(ROOT), body: {
      "id": widget.id,
      "action":'update_location',
      "latitude":latitude,
      "longitude":longitude,
    });
    Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(context, Routes.HOME);

  }
```

and I am passing the argumnets by:

```
onTap: () async{
              Position position= await _determinePosition();
              print(position.latitude);
              print(position.longitude);
              await update_location(position.latitude, position.longitude);
            },
```

when I try to do that there is an exception:

> Unhandled Exception: type 'int' is not a subtype of type 'String' in type cast
> and

> _EnableLocationState.update_location (package:my_cab_driver/introduction/LocationScreen.dart:26:26)
> E/flutter ( 4530): #11     _EnableLocationState.build. (package:my_cab_driver/introduction/LocationScreen.dart:163:23)
> E/flutter ( 4530):

can anyone help me what is wrong here?

Comment: What does this question/issue have to do with PHP?

Comment: php is where i am handling post request.

Comment: Sure, but if those errors come from/are caused by PHP, you need to post the relevant PHP code as well. If the errors doesn't come from/are caused by PHP, then it's irrelevant and the PHP tag should be removed. People here are subscribing to tags so it's important to only add tags that are relevant to the question at hand. You also need to explain exactly where and when those errors are thrown.

Comment: error clearly saying there are some variables which are integers which you are passing through api request , and your api  is accepting string value . I'm not sure which variables are ..!! i think LatLng are integer . so you should convert them into string by doing`update_location(position.latitude.toString(), position.longitude.toString()`  this.

Comment: Generally speaking, you should use some types, this is a real programming language, not javascript. Use it like a real language and it will guide you, use it like javascript and it will scew with you just like javascript.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the [http post function](https://pub.dev/documentation/http/latest/http/post.html), the body parameter can be a `String`, `List<int>`, or `Map<String, String>`, but you are passing a `Map<String, Object>` since you have mixed value types (`String` and `int`). I think you probably don't actually want to pass a `Map<String, String>` since according to the documentation if you did it will assume you are passing data of content type `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`. If you want to send json data set the content type to `application/json` and send the body as a string (using `json.encode`).

```dart
var response = await http.post(
  Uri.parse(ROOT),
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  },
  body: json.encode({
    "id": widget.id,
    "action": 'update_location',
    "latitude": latitude,
    "longitude": longitude,
  }),
);
```

The above code requires the following import:

```dart
import 'dart:convert';
```

Answer (score -1):

Try to Use `toString()` method [here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/int/toString.html) and [here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/num/toString.html)

like

```
print(position.latitude.toString());

position.latitude.toString()
```

Answer (score -1):

I think server giving response as String and you are trying to parse data as int. or may be reverse server giving you value as int & you trying to parse it as String.